# How to run all scenario of same feature file in one browser? using selenium,java,cucumber

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I am using hooks `@Before (to initialize browser instance)` and `@After (to close browser instance)` which means if there are three scenarios in feature file then the browser will open three times and close three times.

I want to run all three scenarios in the single browser instance.

Comment: is there a hook like 'before all' and 'after all' or 'before scenario' and 'after scenario'. I have never used cucumber, the stated hooks are taken from behave, a python BDD implementation package. I think there should be something similar in Cucumber that you can leverage

Comment: Nops, in cucumber only two hooks are there "@Before" and "@After" and which execute before and after each scenario respectively.

Comment: Yep looks like "Cucumber-JVM does not support Around hooks."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [running all cucumber scenarios for a feature in one browser session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41632886/running-all-cucumber-scenarios-for-a-feature-in-one-browser-session)

Comment: its bit different.

Answer (score -2):

Cucumber provides background which lets you set things ups before tests are executed.

The official docs are [here](https://docs.cucumber.io/gherkin/reference/).  Scroll down to background (or CTRL+F background x3).

Feature File:

```
Background:
   Given browser is initialized.

Scenerio: Test 1
   Then browser is running.
```

And you can write the step definition as usual.

Comment: Please check question.

Comment: The background runs once.  Based on my understanding of your question background would work for you - initialize it and set it to a variable in your step definition.  Use variable for your other test, then the final scenario can close the browser.  If you however feel you want to emulate `@BeforeAll` & `@AfterAll` from Junit, I've had luck with https://stackoverflow.com/a/51566725/4867303

Comment: background runs before each scenario in a feature file.

Comment: I stand corrected, apologies.  In the back of my head `@Before` was for that but they're basically the same.  So I would try the link I posted which lets you run something before and after all tests.  That said, is it possible to just combine your scenarios into 1 scenario with multiple `Then` or a `Scenario Outline`?

Comment: Actually simpler solution - put it in background.  Have one function that checks if browser is initialized and if so initialize it.  First scenario that function runs, other scenarios the function short circuits.